# awk quoting program text

Tags: shell, awk, sed, bosh

if I run:

```
awk '/-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressE/ {print "-Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\"}1' rest_gw.sh >> new_gw.sh
```

the command inserts a new line above line `-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressE`

```
-Djava.security.properties=/var/vcap/packages/helpers/data.properties \
-Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressErrors -consoleLog &
```

If I run the following command, it gives: `awk: line 1: runaway string constant "-Dcom.abc. ...`

```
bosh -d test-105 ssh service/0 -c 'sudo /usr/bin/awk "/-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressErrors/ {print \"-Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\\"}1" /var/vcap/data/jobs/gw_rest/*/target/gw.sh >> /tmp/new_gw.sh'
```

Tried:

```
bosh -d test-105 ssh service/0 -c 'sudo /usr/bin/awk '\'/-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressErrors/ {print \"-Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\\"}1\' /var/vcap/data/jobs/gw_rest/*/target/gw.sh >> /tmp/new_gw.sh'
```

no luck so far. can someone suggest the correct way to do it? TYA!

**EDIT:**

sed command as recommended:

```
bosh -d test-105 ssh service/0 -c 'sudo sed '/-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressE/i -Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\' /var/vcap/data/jobs/gw_rest/*/target/gw.sh >> /tmp/new_gw.sh'
```

`unknown flag launcher.suppressE/i'`

This worked finally:

```
bosh -d test-105 ssh service/0 -c "sudo sed '/-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressErrors -consoleLog/i -Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\\' /var/vcap/data/jobs/gw_rest/*/target/gw.sh >> /tmp/new_gw.sh"
```

Comment: Try: `awk '/-jar org\.eclipse\.osgi\.jar --launcher.suppressErrors/ {print "-Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\"}1'`

Comment: Editing your scripts is probably not a good idea. Add a command-line parameter which adds this option if you pass in an option, and omits it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest use `sed` command insert your line as:

```
sed  '/-jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar --launcher.suppressE/i -Dcom.abc.service.gw.enableValidation=false \\' rest_gw.sh >> new_gw.sh
```

It is cleaner and simple.

Comment: agree. we could do it with sed too. just that running the commands in a nested way is causing problems.

Comment: If i run the sed command as it is, it gives `unknown flag launcher.suppressE/i'`. Update the question. If i delete `launcher.suppressE`, it gives `unknown flag D'`. Have seen these problems with awk too.

Comment: You have quoting problem somewhere. I suggest you segment your scripts. to smaller chunks. run them manually in a  sequence, put lots of `echo` messages, use the bash shell to conform with the standards.

Comment: You are right. it was indeed a quoting problem. i've updated the final outcome with `sed`. Thank you! :)